# Como funciona un Linked Server? SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

he estado investigando y tengo ya una idea de como funciona un linked server pero aun no tengo claro una cosa, se que cuando quieres consultar informacion que se encuentra en OTRO SERVIDOR, bueno, pues creas un LINKED SERVER de ese servidor y asi podras ejecutar consultas con la informacion que se encuentar ahí pero mi duda es... puede ser viceversa?
Osea del mismo linked server generado del Servido1 al Servidor2 puedes utilizar la informacion del Servidor2... pero tambien se puede usar la informacion del Servidor1 desde el Servidor2?

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: No, necesitas crear dos linked server en servidor1 y servidor2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se puede. Un linked server es un objeto dentro de la instancia. Este objeto permite conectarse a otro servidor, pero no abre una puerta para que el otro servidor se conecte.

Puesto de otra forma, un linked server es como tener las llaves para otra casa y poder acceder a ella. Pero eso no significa que tengas que dar las llaves de tu casa. Para que los que viven en la otra casa puedan acceder libremente a la tuya, les tienes que entregar las llaves de tu casa.

Answer (score -1):

Sí, puedes configurar un "linked server" en ambos servidores para acceder a la información en ambas direcciones.

Para aclarar, si tienes dos servidores SQL Server, Servidor1 y Servidor2, y deseas acceder a la información de ambos servidores desde cada uno, puedes configurar un "linked server" en cada servidor apuntando al otro.

Entonces, configura un "linked server" en Servidor1 que apunte a Servidor2 y viceversa, configura otro "linked server" en Servidor2 que apunte a Servidor1. De esta manera, puedes ejecutar consultas en Servidor1 que accedan a la información en Servidor2 y también ejecutar consultas en Servidor2 que accedan a la información en Servidor1.

Ejemplo:

En el Servidor1, crea un "linked server" para el Servidor2:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server = 'Servidor2',
@srvproduct = '',
@provider = 'SQLNCLI',
@datasrc = 'nombre_del_servidor2';
```

En el Servidor2, crea un "linked server" para el Servidor1:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server = 'Servidor1',
@srvproduct = '',
@provider = 'SQLNCLI',
@datasrc = 'nombre_del_servidor1';
```

Una vez que hayas configurado los "linked servers" en ambos servidores, podrás ejecutar consultas en cada servidor que accedan a la información del otro. Por ejemplo, si deseas consultar datos de una tabla en el Servidor2 desde el Servidor1, puedes utilizar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM Servidor2.nombre_base_de_datos.esquema.nombre_tabla;
```

Y, de manera similar, si deseas consultar datos de una tabla en el Servidor1 desde el Servidor2, puedes utilizar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM Servidor1.nombre_base_de_datos.esquema.nombre_tabla;
```

también necesitarás configurar la seguridad y los permisos adecuados para permitir el acceso a los "linked servers" en ambos servidores.

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar ; [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.